# Mysql_fetch_data prints unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to do a password verification with MySQL but it does not work. Instead of comparing in the if-clause it prints the MySQL_fetch_object

```
public function __construct($userId, $userPassword) {
    $this->userId = $userId;
    $this->userPassword = $userPassword;
    $connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'php', 'geheim') or exit ();
    $users = mysql_select_db("chat", $connect) or exit ();
    $request = "SELECT userPassword FROM user WHERE userId=$userId";
    $result = mysql_query($result);
    if(mysql_fetch_object($result)->userPassword === $userPassword){
        echo "Right Password";
    }
```

but it only prints this although i never said it should echo it:

> verificateUser Object ( [userId:verificateUser:private] => 1 [userPassword:verificateUser:private] => 12345 )

What am I doing wrong? Thx for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 public function __construct($userId, $userPassword) {
$this->userId = $userId;
$this->userPassword = $userPassword;
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'php', 'geheim') or exit ();
$users = mysql_select_db("chat", $connect) or exit ();
$request = "SELECT userPassword FROM user WHERE userId=$userId";
$result = mysql_query($result);
$userpass =mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($userpass['userPassword'] == $userPassword){
    echo "Right Password";
}
}
```

**EDIT:** if you interested about this method below

```
 public function __construct($userId, $userPassword) {
$this->userId = $userId;
$this->userPassword = $userPassword;
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'php', 'geheim') or exit ();
$users = mysql_select_db("chat", $connect) or exit ();
$request = "SELECT userPassword FROM user WHERE userId=$userId";
$result = mysql_query($result);
$userpass =mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($userpass['userPassword'] == $userPassword){
   return true:
}
return false;
}
```

Then you can check like that

```
  if(__construct($userId, $userPassword) == true) { you welcome}
  if(__construct($userId, $userPassword) == false) {do your pass again}
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an assoc array not an object probably mean `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)["userPassword"]` and that direct use of array notation on returns is only allowed on the newer editions so on older ones you need two lines to get the value.

Comment: @sunfingerde Just edited my answer i think its better if you maybe interested about the reutrn and checking purpose.